# Verification of Gerber file layers

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-fabrication, gerber

I have old PCB Altium design files and Gerber files. I want to cross check Gerbers with design files. However I'm trying by visually checking, but I know that's not a smart technique to do that. Is there any smart and optimized technique for cross-checking?

Comment: You could export the design files as Gerbers, then use a Gerber comparison tool.

Comment: Altium has an online Gerber compare tool at https://www.altium.com/gerber-compare/

Comment: @JYelton can you suggest any free camparison tool.

Comment: @BhushanWaghe I don't know of any free ones, at one time I used a non-free predecessor to [Numerical Innovations' FAB 3000](https://www.numericalinnovations.com/collections/fab-3000-gerber-cam). (This is why I posted as a comment instead of an answer.)

Comment: Thank you JYelton

Answer (score 1):

I use BeyondCompare from Scooter SW because we are not allowed to upload our design to any online storage including Altium.

As BeyondCompare can compare pictures pixelwise and mark all differences you can directly use this to compare the Gerber files of a PCB layer by layer. The Standard version for about $35,- is enough

For both PCB Versions:
1. Open the Gerber files in Altium Designer CAMtastic
2. Enable only the Layer of interest (single layer mode)
3. File -> export -> Bitmap
4. Mark the whole PCB (let mouse click)
5. End marking mode via right mouse click
6. Select DPI=1000 and Color scheme = monochrome
7. Save

Compare them in Beyond Compare
Choose the Pixel tolerance as you like

Answer (score 1):

Use any Gerber viewer, load both designs and give similar layers, eg GTL on both designs, different colors. You will see the areas where the layers differ, since the colors won't mix there.